# Swift Version Compatibility Issue in CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a question about framework creation in Swift. While I hold it on the Cocoapods, and other users install it, they are facing the Swift compiler error(xyz framework compiles swift 5.8.2 while you are using 5.9.2).

What is the solution for this if we are using Swift. I want a universal release which is free from these kinds of errors.

I also used `Build Libraries for Distribution` = `YES`.

Comment: Are you distributing your framework as source code or as compiled framework?  If you are distributing a compiled framework you should use the latest Xcode to compile it.

Comment: @Paulw11 we are distributing as compiled framework and if I am using latest Xcode and user have previous version than still he is facing issue due to unmatch swift version.

Comment: Developers will typically always be using the latest Xcode because it is a requirement to submit apps to the app store (eg ios 17 SDK is mandatory from April but most developers will be using it already). Even if they are using an older version they can upgrade to use your framework. A developer with the latest is not going to want to downgrade their Xcode

Comment: You also need  set `Skip Install` to `NO` to enable module stability

Comment: Yes, that is odd. With module stability should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Module stability only works in one direction, because new features get added over time. Binary distributions need to build with the earliest version of Xcode supported for client usage.